Sci-fi film about a terminally ill scientist who prevents an alien device in the Himalayas from resetting life on Earth
I'm looking to identify this film where the lead character is a male American or Canadian scientist. Early in the film, he is declared terminally ill. He goes to join the investigation of an alien object in the Himalayas. He meets a woman with whom he once had a relationship.
It becomes apparent that the device wants to reset life on Earth. He and his lady friend prevent this. The device cures his illness. The final scene shows him delivering a lecture, then leaving the room with his female friend, with whom he has been reconciled.

Hi, welcome to Movie & TV.  Do you recall when and where you saw this?

Why would you vote this as "needs details or clarity"? I see at least fifteen strong pieces of relevant info. Narrowing it down to a single film should be a doddle. It's a Film. Science fiction. Male scientist is the hero. Probably American. Investigates a discovery. Discovery is an alien device. Device is in the Himalayas. He's terminally ill. He teams up with his ex. The device wants to reset life on Earth. He prevents this. The device cures his illness. He delivers a lecture at the end. He leaves with his ex. They have reconciled.

This is Epoch (2001).
The main character is a terminally ill scientist who travels to Bhutan to investigate an alien artifact that ultimately cures him.



